# How should I use a hibernated DAO in my application?

Tags: java, hibernate, relational-database

I have created a data model using hibernate and data model is ready and now I want to use this data model using javaEE(web) + spring MVC now I want to know how can I access to my model?
I know I have to create a sessionFacoty and stuffs like that but If I want to do this for each and every class then there is no serious point of using ORM is there any way to integrate the request to sessionFactories?
one of the most important request : searching + filtering data

regards

Comment: this question is a bit broad. have you tried to find some answer from spring reference document?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely broad - id suggest working through a tutorial, such as http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-hibernate-persistence, thn returning here with specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have generic DAO implementation. you can use annotations for wiring DAO beans in your application. It will cut down lots of boiler plate code. Please refer following link:
http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/

Yes you can have generic implementation of search and filter functions but they are reflection based. So you might want to see if the performance of such method is applicable to you or not. you can use hybrid approach like use generic method where ever its performance is OK with you. For other cases you can have your specialized DAO implementation using HQL and/or Criteria query focusing on improving performance.